# iCloud Drive folders not showing on OS X

Tags: macos, finder, icloud

I am seeing some strange behaviour.
As you can see here:
[image]

I have lots of folders I don't see on my Mac (shown here): 
[image]
Not sure why this is. When ever I make a new file or folder on either my Mac or on iCloud.com I see the file/folder. It's just I don't see those default Quicktime folders etc.

Comment: are you sure any files are in there ?

Comment: heya, no the folders are empty - (clean install). surely they should show up though no?

Comment: I read somewhere they would not show if empty, to test put something in it.